# Dispose Angular 2 App or Component

Tags: angular

Is there anyway to dispose angular2 app or component? I'm doing a mixed ASP.NET MVC and Angular 2 app which ASP.NET MVC loads partial views including Angular 2 App. Now I need a close button for each partial view to remove itself from the DOM and dispose loaded angular 2 inside the view to avoid memory leak. Is there anyway to kill angular 2 app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

`.dispose()` is `destroy()` **since beta.16**

**original**

When you bootstrap a component, you get a `ComponentRef` of the root component (`AppComponent`). To dispose it call its `dispose()` method:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}])
    .then((ref) => {
      setTimeout(()=> {
        ref.dispose();
      }, 3000);
    });
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

(You can assign the `ref` variable somewhere for later reuse. This is just to demonstrate that an Angular application can be disposed.)

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/QXvKgf?p=preview)